# Google Wallet in the United Kingdom

Tags: android-pay

I am developing a website and it accepts payments for membership, paid using Google Wallet.

The DEV environment works. The call back function is intercepted, authorised, and the membership is automatically extended as expected.

The remotely hosted environment which should go live soon doesn't want to know.

When the user clicks on buy, an error message immediately pops up. It is ok for the user, but it doesn't say much else, making it useless for the developer. Maybe it's just me not finding the error code, or something similarly useful?

Anyway, the originated JWT String is valid ( the decoder here http://openidtest.uninett.no/jwt decodes it correctly, and the data in it is right ).

Any suggestions on how to fix?

I don't know if this is necessary at this stage or not, and possibly the cause, but the bank account hasn't been verified yet. ( For the developing I used the standard provided US sandbox account, I really hope that Google Wallet accepts UK bank accounts too, can anybody out there confirm? )

Comment: Is the "live" site using [production settings](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial#7)? You can't mix. BTW am assuming _Wallet for Digital_ is the API you're referring to....hth

Comment: Yes, it is Wallet for Digital. I had a few problems setting it up because quite a few times there were links redirecting to checkout which is about to be decommissioned. Clicking on the link you provided ( thanks  for that ) opens up the details that I am submitting. I am sure that they are the ones being used because they are printed out in a log. <br/>The only thing maybe worth adding is that maybe I changed the postback URL - I am not sure, maybe I didn't. So, if the seller Secret is based on that, that could be a problem.

Comment: It _could_ be the postback url (signature verification). So if your postback url doesn't acknowledge (e.g. signature verification fails) [Google will cancel](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/postback#responding). Hth...

Comment: Google doesn't even attempt to post a verification call to the postback URL ( again, a System.out.println placed in the code called by the URL ). It has the correct one anyway... When the users click on buy, they get a pop up error message straight away, instead of the normal popup which allows them to proceed. So the problem lies before that, but I can't work out what it is because I don't know how to intercept the error message. There is a failureHandler in the page, which I assume is for this type of problem, but I can't get it to do anything. Even if I leave it alone in the page as it is.

Comment: I looked at this - https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/jsreference#failurehandler - but nothing is printed out in the console, or nothing appears if I put an alert anywhere.

Comment: I changed browser and I am getting some reaction from it. I will post in a bit if there is any relevant information.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the whole system I believe. The alert pop up, untouched, sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. If there is a method to display the error code I guess I will find it tomorrow.

Comment: Sorted! I was using the correct JWT data for the live environment. I just needed a good sleep to find out that I was loading the wrong environment... If somebody finds him/her self in the same situation, make sure you are using "<script src="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/lib/buy.js"></script>" for production, and not "    <script src="https://wallet.google.com/inapp/lib/buy.js"></script>"

Comment: I do not know how to flag this thread as solved...

Comment: Actually, it goes back to my first comment - you **can't mix sandbox and production code/settings/accounts**. Your comment is misleading - it seems you're saying use "sandbox" stuff for "production" which **is not** the case.

Comment: Absolutely... I just forgot that the imported script is part of the environment. It was late and I had JTWs coming out of my ears because of previous problems... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem, as mentioned above. Best is to follow the steps above in case you do have problems caused by a missing one, different from mine. A big thank you to EdSF for his help! :)